# Error: The argument type 'JsObject' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add height and width for my image but this error is being showed up. I'm a beginner to flutter and dart language.

```
import 'dart:js';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:PPG/homePage.dart';
import 'constants.dart';

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                image,
                height: height * 0.4,
                width: width,
              )])],
          )),
      }
}
```

Comment: You should really start indenting your code, otherwise it becomes totally unreadable

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and format it properly.

Comment: I have adjusted the coding now. Hope you can read it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've imported by mistake the `dart:js` module. If so, just remove it:

```dart
import 'dart:js'; // <- Remove this import
```

[The `dart:js` module exports a global `context` of type `JsObject`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-js/context.html) and its type conflicts with the `BuildContext` type.